# Why does this code print the same thing twice?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, timeout

I am trying to write some small timeout code:

```
t = Thread.new { sleep 3 } # <- The thread that will do stuff.
Thread.new { sleep 2; t.kill; p 'hi!' } # <- The thread that will kill it after two seconds.
t.join
```

If the first thread completes it's job within two seconds, it will stop, and the main thread will have nothing to do. This will cause the program to exit before the second thread gets to the `t.kill` part. But, when I run this code, `"hi!"` gets printed out twice. Replacing the `p` with `puts` fixes it. Why does this happen?

Comment: @Marc: I have found that if you type `ruby` into a terminal (without arguments) and just paste the code in and press Control-D, `"hi"` will only get printed once. But if you actually put the code into a file and do something like `ruby test.rb`, it will happen. I think it may have something to do with the speed at which ruby can read a file vs. the speed at which ruby can read stdin.

Comment: Definitely a bug. `ruby somefile.rb` will print it twice most of the time, it's intermittent. Could file it on redmine.ruby-lang.org ? You can specify "ruby 1.9.3dev (2010-07-19 trunk 28679) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]" for `ruby -v`, as I've reproduced this with trunk. Or let me know and I'll create the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby had a bug with io buffering and threading that looks exactly like this. It has been fixed recently, so upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like "hi!" is getting buffered up and flushed twice, once by the anonymous thread that did the `p` operation, and once by the main thread.  If this were a C program, the way to fix it would be to disable buffering on `stdout`, or else to use `write` to fd 1, bypassing stdio.  Presumably Ruby has an equivalent at least of the first of these options?